# How to represent an entity with an existing UUID in Datomic?

Tags: clojure, datomic

**Background**

We have multiple services that communicates via events. Many events are referring to some entity using a (globally) unique surrogate id that is present in the event. For example "CustomerRegisteredEvent" (E) may contain the id of the registered customer. When using other databases I could typically persist a "Customer" entity with an id corresponding to the id (and other values) present in (E).

In datomic I typically see the use of `tempid` to generate an id for a new entity but I'm not clear if I should use this approach when a UUID is known beforehand?

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to generate a Datomic id based on the id in the event?
2. If not, does one typically just create a new attribute for the "original" (event) id? Something like:

   `{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
     :db/ident :customer/uuid
     :db/valueType :db.type/string
     :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
     :db/doc "The original UUID of the customer"
     :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ignore the Datomic `:db/id` as an internal detail (just like you ignore the Git hash of a commit as an internal detail).  Use the solution (2) in your question, except that you probably want to use the built-in type `:db.type/uuid` instead of string.

You may also be interested in looking at [the Tupelo-Datomic library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo-datomic), which contains a number of helper and convenience functions for interacting with Datomic.

Enjoy!

P.S.  Don't overlook the Datomic function `d/squuid` for generating semi-sequential UUIDs, which are a more efficient way of generating *new* UUIDs in Datomic

---

**Update**:  Adding data to Datomic is somewhat confusing and is more complicated than it needs to be.  That is why you can use Tupelo-Datomic to simplify the whole operation:

```
(td/transact *conn*
  (td/new-entity { :person/name "James Bond" :location "London"     :weapon/type #{ :weapon/gun :weapon/wit   } } )
  (td/new-entity { :person/name "M"          :location "London"     :weapon/type #{ :weapon/gun :weapon/guile } } )
  (td/new-entity { :person/name "Dr No"      :location "Caribbean"  :weapon/type    :weapon/gun                 } ))
```

One of the things Tupelo-Datomic does for you is to silently add the boilerplate for:   `{:db/id (d/tempid -partition) }`

Comment: Hmm maybe I'm doing something wrong but when not defining `:db/id` I end up with:

`datomic.impl.Exceptions$IllegalArgumentExceptionInfo: :db.error/entity-missing-db-id Missing :db/id`

`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: :db.error/entity-missing-db-id Missing :db/id`

Comment: You still need to create a temp id, but you just ignore whatever permanent id Datomic creates for you.